# How to split a text after <tag> ... </tag>?

Tags: javascript

I want to split a text when a headline was found.

The headline always starts with `<p><strong>` and ends with `</strong></p>`.

The text between are always different.

```
<p><strong>Omnis officiis qui hic mollitia<br /><br /></strong></p>

<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit mollitia cupiditate ab eaque exercitationem. Omnis officiis qui hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p>

<p><strong>Quibusdam alias dolor a</strong></p>

<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p>
<ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li></ul>

<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong></p>

<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Assumenda aspernatur sit, cumque autem in suscipit laudantium natus, dolore, non molestiae optio alias reiciendis cum. Asperiores autem doloribus repellendus minima eaque? Earum iure inventore minima soluta ex vitae nostrum, aut nulla enim maxime rerum doloremque aperiam commodi! Numquam, nemo commodi! Consequuntur nulla sint dolorem itaque eveniet veritatis repellat? Saepe dignissimos esse vero? Impedit reprehenderit officiis beatae blanditiis</span></p>
```

In my example i want to get this result:

```
[
    0: "<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit mollitia cupiditate ab eaque exercitationem. Omnis officiis qui hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p>",
    1: "<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p><ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li></ul>",
    2: "<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Assumenda aspernatur sit, cumque autem in suscipit laudantium natus, dolore, non molestiae optio alias reiciendis cum. Asperiores autem doloribus repellendus minima eaque? Earum iure inventore minima soluta ex vitae nostrum, aut nulla enim maxime rerum doloremque aperiam commodi! Numquam, nemo commodi! Consequuntur nulla sint dolorem itaque eveniet veritatis repellat? Saepe dignissimos esse vero? Impedit reprehenderit officiis beatae blanditiis</span></p>"
]
```

How i can get this result?

Comment: In the expected output, the element at index `1` includes one of the "headlines" while all of the others don't. Is that intentional, or is it an error?

Comment: this is an error, sorry i removed the line

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76700032/how-to-split-a-text-after-tag-tag#comment135223796_76700032) Now it looks like you've missed the unordered list element text. Shouldn't the output have 4 strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) the input string (which represents a fragment of HTML child elements) and [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) the parsed [child elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), collecting [serialized representations of them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) into an array of strings:

```js
function isHeading(element) {
  return element.tagName === "P" && element.firstChild?.tagName === "STRONG";
}

const text = `
<p><strong>Omnis officiis qui hic mollitia<br /><br /></strong></p>

<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit mollitia cupiditate ab eaque exercitationem. Omnis officiis qui hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p>

<p><strong>Quibusdam alias dolor a</strong></p>

<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p>
<p><strong>Was Sie mitbringen:</strong></p>
<ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li></ul>

<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong></p>

<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Assumenda aspernatur sit, cumque autem in suscipit laudantium natus, dolore, non molestiae optio alias reiciendis cum. Asperiores autem doloribus repellendus minima eaque? Earum iure inventore minima soluta ex vitae nostrum, aut nulla enim maxime rerum doloremque aperiam commodi! Numquam, nemo commodi! Consequuntur nulla sint dolorem itaque eveniet veritatis repellat? Saepe dignissimos esse vero? Impedit reprehenderit officiis beatae blanditiis</span></p>
`;

const htmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");

const strings = [];
let current = "";

const finalize = () => {
  if (current.trim()) strings.push(current);
  current = "";
};

// Your input HTML fragment text is inserted into the document's `body` element:
for (const element of htmlDocument.body.children) {
  if (isHeading(element)) finalize();
  else current += element.outerHTML;
}

finalize();

for (const [index, string] of strings.entries()) {
  console.log(index, string);
}
```

Here's a static copy of the console output from the code snippet above:

```txt
0 '<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit mollitia cupiditate ab eaque exercitationem. Omnis officiis qui hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p>'
1 '<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Hic mollitia molestiae eveniet porro ducimus sint? Sint sapiente quibusdam alias dolor a voluptatem, minus velit placeat fugit. Eum nulla omnis eaque dicta!</span></p>'
2 '<ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Ducimus sint</li></ul>'
3 '<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Assumenda aspernatur sit, cumque autem in suscipit laudantium natus, dolore, non molestiae optio alias reiciendis cum. Asperiores autem doloribus repellendus minima eaque? Earum iure inventore minima soluta ex vitae nostrum, aut nulla enim maxime rerum doloremque aperiam commodi! Numquam, nemo commodi! Consequuntur nulla sint dolorem itaque eveniet veritatis repellat? Saepe dignissimos esse vero? Impedit reprehenderit officiis beatae blanditiis</span></p>'
```

Comment: Really nice implementation. Good job